# Restart systemd unit on certain log output

Tags: systemd

I am trying to run a program as a systemd unit. This was not originally designed to be one, and it seems that it sometimes posts errors to stdout instead of stderr, while prefixing the message with `Error`.
Rather than trying to modify the program and rebuilding it, I was hoping there might be a way to have systemd monitor the log output for the keyword `Error` and restart the service in that case.

Is there a way to achieve this, whether it's native in systemd or somehow by wrapping this program in a pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a small wrapper script in Python that monitors the output and exits the process if the error line appears in its output.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess
import atexit
import sys

ALL_PROCESSES = []


def exit_handler():
    for process in ALL_PROCESSES:
        process.kill()


def main():
    global ALL_PROCESSES
    process = subprocess.Popen(<what-to-execute>,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True)
    ALL_PROCESSES.append(process)
    while True:
        nextline = process.stdout.readline()
        if nextline == '' and process.poll() is not None:
            break
        if 'error' in nextline.lower():
            sys.stderr.write('Error occured, stopping child: {}'.format(nextline))
            exit_handler()
            sys.exit(1)
        sys.stdout.write(nextline)
        sys.stdout.flush()

    output = process.communicate()[0]
    exitCode = process.returncode

    if (exitCode == 0):
        return output
    else:
        raise ProcessException(command, exitCode, output)


def execute(cmd):
    popen = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
    for stdout_line in iter(popen.stdout.readline, ""):
        yield stdout_line
    popen.stdout.close()
    return_code = popen.wait()
    if return_code:
        raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(return_code, cmd)


atexit.register(exit_handler)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```